# Random Module help in python

Tags: python-3.x, random, pygame

So here I have my code to connect 3 game. In order for me to proceed to finish coding the rest of the game, I need your help fixing the loop that determines what player goes first. When the loop randomly selects the player, it blits it's token however it keeps bliting both of the players tokens which means that the random function keeps running. How do I fix it so it runs once. Thanks!

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import*

#FPS
FPS =7
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Display
DISPLAYSURF=pygame.display.set_mode((850, 725), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Connect 3~Emoji Edition')


#Colors
WHITE=(255, 255, 255)

#Players
Player1='P1'
Player2='P2'


#Images

#Keyboard
Board=pygame.image.load('Keyboard.png')
Boardx=45
Boardy=200


#Token1
Token1=pygame.image.load('PoopEMJ.png')
Token1=pygame.transform.scale(Token1, (90, 90))
Token1x=375
Token1y=215


#Token2
Token2=pygame.image.load('LaughingEMJ.png')
Token2=pygame.transform.scale(Token2, (90, 90))
Token2x=375
Token2y=215


while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(Board,(Boardx, Boardy))


#Randomly selects players *HELP*
    Turn='Player'
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        Turn = Player1
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(Token1,(Token1x, Token1y))

    else:
        Turn = Player2
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(Token2,(Token2x, Token2y))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Where is your `break` statement to break out of the while loop? Alternatively, put the if-else in an if-statement that test whether `Turn` is defined to be `Player1` or `Player2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the code to randomly select the player, in the `While True` loop.
This means that it will constantly select a new random player and blit it to the screen. you must only select a new random player when the last player has finished their turn, or it is the beginning of the game.